# LINQ - двойная групировка с посчетом количества элементов

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Допустим есть список элементов

```
public class PlanesLogRow
{
    public DateTime ArriveDate;
    public string Origin;
    public string Destination;
}
```

1. нужно достать из него список всех аэропортов `(Origin + Destination).Distinct()`
2. нужно посчитать для каждого аэропорта arrived самолеты и left.

формально, за один линк запрос нужно создать тупл вроде `<airport, AsOriginCount, AsDestinationCount>`

если достать список всех аєропортов совсем не проблема, то как делать одновременно 2 групировки по разным параметрам?

Если можно, приведите пример одновременно отдельно под SQL и отдельно под C# Linq -- хочу разобратся в обоих вариантах реализации даной фильтрации.

Comment: `planes.Select(a => new { Airport = a.Origin, Origin = 1, Destination = 0 }).Concat(planes.Select(a => new { Airport = a.Destination, Origin = 0, Destination = 1 })).GroupBy(a => a.Airport).Select(g => new { Airport = g.Key, AsOriginCount = g.Sum(a => a.Origin), AsDestinationCount = g.Sum(a => a.Destination) })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rez2 = planes.SelectMany(p => new[] {
         new { Airport = p.Origin, IsOrigin = true },
         new { Airport = p.Destination, IsOrigin = false }
       })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Airport)
       .Select(g => new
       {
           Airport = g.Key,
           LeftCount = g.Count(x => x.IsOrigin),
           ArrivedCount = g.Count(x => !x.IsOrigin)
       });
```